# Record video and sound from device camera and show it as a texture

Tags: unity, camera, ios, video

I need to record and show video from a real camera device in iOS/Unity and show that video as a texture in RawImage ([Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulkG.png))

What I have tried so far:

- **[Unity WebCamTexture API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html)**: It shows the camera in a texture but it has two problems! It does not record audio and does not have an API to save video!
- **[Camera Capture Plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/camera-capture-104588)**: I bought this plugin but unfortunately it does not have the feature to show video in a texture; it just opens the camera device's application.
- **[EverPlay plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/everyplay-16005)**: I tried this plugin and it seems that it just creates a video from the screen and not the camera
- **[Unity Video Capture API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html)**: There is also this API for recording video with sound but unfortunately it is part of Windows Mixed Reality and does not support iOS
- **Using Objective C**: I tried to write the video recording section directly in Objective C, I did it but I could not find a way to embed that in the Unity scene -- I'm not sure it's even possible! (
  [what I tried)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8cJs.png)

I appreciate any other solutions that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you targeting Metal or OpenGL?

I would suggest taking a look at [CreateExternalTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture.html)

This lets you basically take an `id<MTLTexture>` (Metal) or `GLuint` pointing to a native texture (OpenGL) and turn it into a Unity texture.

You can use `AVFoundation` to get the video and stream it to a Metal texture. Here is Apple’s [example project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalVideoCapture/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015131) which does that part.

Comment: ty for your response, It helps. actually, I ended up adding save functionality in unity's ios source code( which like you said uses AVFoundation for its webcamtexture API)